# i'm getting error when i'm trying to install cx_Oracle library for python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
# python -m pip install cx_Oracle
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Using cached cx_Oracle-8.3.0.tar.gz (363 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cx_Oracle
  Building wheel for cx_Oracle (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cx_Oracle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      <string>:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jb_g39xc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\expand.py:134: SetuptoolsWarning: File 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u3v1mhmi\\cx-oracle_552b461268374c8e84e109da373d4d00\\README.md' cannot be found
        return '\n'.join(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'cx_Oracle' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
# ERROR:** Failed building wheel for cx_Oracle
# Failed to build cx_Oracle
# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cx_Oracle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

please give me any valid solution

Comment: Have you read and followed the instruction _"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"_

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to install the Microsoft Build tools in order to build cx_Oracle for yourself, or you can install python-oracledb instead. This is the replacement for cx_Oracle and can be installed via:

```
python -m pip install oracledb
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html) for details on the upgrade.